# Meaning of Values for PostTypeId in data explorer or in data-dump

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I am looking for some explanation of the schema for the [data dump of se sites](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Specifically I'd like to know the values for `PostTypeId` field (1=Questions?, 2=Answers?, 3=?, etc).

I have tried to look for it, I am sure it must be posted somewhere pretty obvious, but I seem to have a blind spot that I need help with.

Comment: I changed my mind about the duplicate, since the documentation is so far behind

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - In that case, isn't the solution to [edit the original, canonical post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/2678/edit)?  It's got 40 upvotes and 24 revisions, I hardly think that we should start a new question for it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can get it by:

```
select * from posttypes
```

It returns:

```
1 Question
2 Answer
3 Wiki
4 TagWikiExcerpt
5 TagWiki
6 ModeratorNomination
7 WikiPlaceholder
8 PrivilegeWiki
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks. Duh, I knew it was obvious.

Answer (score 16):

In theory [selecting from PostTypes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99265/values-for-posttypeid-in-data-explorer/99267#99267) should be the right way, but it seems to be behind, since I see 1-6 used in the PostTypeId field. The `readme.txt` file in the data dump is worse; it only lists 1 and 2 for Question and Answer, respectively. I looked at 20 random posts from each ID; they appear to be:

- 1 -- Questions
- 2 -- Answers
- 3 -- Orphan Tag Wikis (tag wikis for tags that have since been deleted. ♦ mods can see these live)
- 4 -- Tag Wiki Excerpts
- 5 -- Tag Wiki Bodys
- 6 -- [Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) nominations

Comment: Thank you, interesting... btw, is there somewhere where I can look more directly on the schema, integrity rules, etc... +1

Comment: There's documentation in the `readme.txt` that comes with the data dump; it's reproduced [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer). That's all that's publicly available