# Where can I see how many points of reputation I have lost from all my deleted posts (without doing it manually)?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-posts

I'm an active member on Mathematics.

Where can I see how much reputation I have lost with all my deleted posts (not to do it manually)?

Answer (score 3):

You can *semi-automatically* get this by adding up the reputation earned numbers in the [annual reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/69/year/math) pages. The number displayed for reputation earned within a given time frame [excludes changes as a result of "private" reputation events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141691/323179) such as deleted posts. Therefore, if you add up the reputation numbers that the league shows you as having earned every year (the longest period available for which that number is shown), and subtract that from your current rep, you'll get the overall gain/loss in rep that happened because of "private" reputation events.

Keep in mind that said "private" reputation events also exclude the 1 rep you lose from downvoting answers (as well as the -100 penalty for posting spam or abuse), so to get the actual true number you'll need to add to your prior calculation the number of answers you've downvoted, which you'll have to either manually count in the "votes" tab on your user profile, or use [this trick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179031/how-can-i-find-answers-ive-downvoted) to extract them from the `/reputation` page (assuming you haven't received any -100 penalties for spam or abuse).

tl;dr: you can get that number with the following formula:

```
Your current rep
 - SUM(Reputation earned per year, as displayed in annual rep league pages)
 + Number of answers you've downvoted
 + (Number of posts deleted as spam or abusive, for which the red flags weren't cleared) * 100
 = Amount of rep you've gained or lost due to deleted posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this SEDE query: [Shows all deleted answers for the specified user](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/972057/find-deleted-questions-by-user), your user number is 463553 and the result is:

[image: SEDE Query]

You'll see more information if you run the query yourself and scroll sideways. The posttypeid can be edited: [Meaning of Values for PostTypeId in data explorer or in data-dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99265/meaning-of-values-for-posttypeid-in-data-explorer-or-in-data-dump).

Comment: First of all, this only returns answers, not all posts. You also need the score breakdown (because +3 could be +53/-50). Then, you need to make sure that the post did not meet the criteria for the points to be kept (which I think is a score of +3 and the post is at least 60 days old when it is deleted).